# Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor

Tags: struts2

I'm getting the following error when i try to run a simple application using struts2. Could you tell me the solution?

```
Dec 22, 2010 1:50:47 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder constructInterceptorReference
WARNING: Unable to load config class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor at interceptor - jar:file:/E:/Eclipseworkspace/MyTestJava/WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.0.9.jar!/struts-default.xml:76:115 probably due to a missing jar, which might be fine if you never plan to use the debugging interceptor
Dec 22, 2010 1:50:47 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder constructInterceptorReference
SEVERE: Actual exception
Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor - interceptor - jar:file:/E:/Eclipseworkspace/MyTestJava/WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.0.9.jar!/struts-default.xml:76:115
 at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(StrutsObjectFactory.java:78)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:57)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:905)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStack(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:743)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptorStacks(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:756)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadInterceptors(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:777)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:410)


Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager, name='default'] in public void org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.setFreemarkerManager(org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager).
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing struts2-config-browser-plugin.i know this is a bit old thread but that's what worked for me. I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Check line 76, character 115 of your

```
struts-default.xml
```

Some jar seems to be missing

Comment: i placed almost all jars which i  used for my previous project